# "Don't keep activities" option in Android Studio?

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

I'm trying to test for low memory conditions in my Android app, and I've read here that I should activate the "Don't keep activities" option in Developer Options to test my onSaveInstanceState code.

Unfortunately, I can't find that option in Studio. (Is it only available in Eclipse?)

Is it possible to set this option in Studio?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an option in the device itself. It is under the Developer Options menu - near the bottom under the Apps heading.

If you have not already, you will need to enable the Developer Options menu by clicking a bunch of times on the Build Number in About Phone under Settings.